# Visual Studio auto complete is not working - VS 17.5 Mac/Unity3d

Tags: macos, visual-studio

Visual Studio auto complete is not working after updating to 17.5.

Also, when googling the preference view looks different and the "Insert matching brace" is greyed out. See picture.

I did read somewhere that this may be a bug but I am not sure and I have not been able to find that info again.

Anyone that can advise me how to fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is now a reported bug at Microsoft.

[https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/大括号无法补全/10237724](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/%E5%A4%A7%E6%8B%AC%E5%8F%B7%E6%97%A0%E6%B3%95%E8%A1%A5%E5%85%A8/10237724)

**UPDATE March 7, 2023 (Fixed pending release)**

The problem with the Preferences UI disabling the brace matching option checkbox has been corrected internally and will be released with a 17.5 servicing release due to be released publicly very soon. The issue with brace matching behavior failing intermittently is a different issue that we will continue to investigate using the folloiwng feedback item to track the issue: [https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/大括号无法补全/10237724](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/%E5%A4%A7%E6%8B%AC%E5%8F%B7%E6%97%A0%E6%B3%95%E8%A1%A5%E5%85%A8/10237724)

Thank you,
Allen Denver
Visual Studio for Mac

**UPDATE March 7 2023 (from Microsoft)**

Thanks - we’re aware that the brace completion isn’t totally solved yet. We’re seeing this on some machines and not others, and it seems to come and go as well. We’re still looking at the problem - the fact that this is a bit elusive particularly under the debugger is making this challenging. It’s still a top issue we’re chasing down.

Thank you for your continued patience and trying the latest update!